# Tought nut to convert from parameterized form to implicit form

Tags: calculus, parametrization

I have the parameter form:

\begin{equation}
x=\frac{1}{\cos t}\\
y=2\tan t
\end{equation}

which I want to convert to implicit form. This turns out to be quite hard. One attempt is to set the square of each side of both eqns. and get:

\begin{equation}
x^2=\frac{1}{\cos^2 t}\\
y^2=4\tan^2t
\end{equation}

which is:

\begin{equation}
x^2=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos2t)}\\
y^2=4\frac{1-\cos2t}{1+\cos2t}
\end{equation}

For simplicity set $\cos2t=u$ and rearrange.

\begin{equation}
x^2(1+u)=2\\
y^2(1+u)=4(1-u)
\end{equation}

From here we get to

\begin{equation}
(1+u)=\frac{2}{x^2}\\
(1+u)=\frac{4(1-u)}{y^2}
\end{equation}

But this seems to go nowhere. Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

$x =\sec t$ and $\sec^{2}t=1+\tan^{2}t$ so we get $x^{2}=1+\frac {y^{2}}4$. This is a hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks for this